# переадача массива в фрагмент

Tags: android, массивы, android-fragment, recyclerview

Есть массив например`massive{3,5,6}` его надо передать во фрагмент с такими же значениями `massive{3,5,6}`

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    int bundle=3;
    Bundle bundlee;
     int[] arrayP;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    }

    private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {

        final ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        Random rnd = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());
         arrayP = new int[bundle];
        for (int i = 0; i < bundle; i++) {
            int pp = 100 + rnd.nextInt(1000 - 100 + 1);
            arrayP[i] = pp;
        }
        bundlee = new Bundle();
        bundlee.putIntArray("arrayP",arrayP);
        OneFragment Fragment1 = new OneFragment();
        Fragment1.setArguments(bundlee);
        adapter.addFragment(Fragment1, "");
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

}


public class OneFragment extends Fragment {
    public OneFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;
    ArrayList<Processor> dataModels;
    private static .. adapter;
    int[] arrayP;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, container, false);

        final int bundle = getActivity().getIntent().getExtras().getInt("P");
        final int RAM = getActivity().getIntent().getExtras().getInt("R");
        arrayP = getActivity().getIntent().getExtras().getIntArray("arrayP");
        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);

        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        dataModels = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < bundle; i++) {
            arrayP[i] = i;
            dataModels.add(new //(arraP[i]);
        }
        adapter = new ....(dataModels, getContext());
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        return view;
    }
}
```

Рандомна в активити задаю числа например масс=[23,41,12],но во фрагмент с такими числами массив не передается ,и выбивает ошибку `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to write to null array`

Comment: А где вызывается метод setupViewPager()?

Comment: в OnCreate я его просто убрал,он есть ,просто сократил код,проблема здесь не в этом

Answer (score 2):

Для того чтобы получить аргументы фрагмента, вам не нужно активити. Необходимо выполнить что-то вроде:

```
arrayP = getArguments().getIntArray("arrayP");
```

в onCreateView вашего фрагмента.

Comment: было бы не плохо полный пример

Comment: Зачем? Просто замените 
        arrayP = getActivity().getIntent().getExtras().getIntArray("arrayP"); на то, что я предлагаю.

Comment: изменил как вы сказали,выводит 0,1,2 хотя я задавал рандомные числа значит не правильно передалось

Comment: Мне кажется, для тестирования лучше передать что-то конкретное, а не рандомное и проверить оно ли пришло.

Comment: можете проверить код выше ,и сказать правильно ли я вообще в массив записываю рандомные числа ,и правильно ли инициализирую массив?

Comment: У вас зачем-то ниже выполняется в цикле команда arrayP[i] = i; Здесь элементы массива как раз и получают значения 0, 1, 2. Скорее всего изначально они правильные

Comment: а как вывести полученный массив?заполненный

Comment: Ну вы ведь как-то увидели эти 0, 1, 2. Так же и посмотрите. Только не выполняйте команду arrayP[i] = i;